# Excel resize range to end at specific column index

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range I get from Selection.Rows.

How can I resize the range selection to end a a specific column index?

Such as if the range is A1 : A25 how can I dynamically resize it to A1 : A4 programatically?

Cheers.

Edit:

I want to resize the current selection to end at a particular column..?

Comment: what do you mean? What do you want to resize? Please provide more details with your question

Answer (score 2):

```
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A25")

Set rng = rng.resize(4,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count, 16).Select

Solved it.